# How to integrate sanitizer report with gtest and/or Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, googletest, sanitizer

I have some multi platform project and address sanitizer found couple issues when running gtest unit tests (issues are from dependencies which where not build with sanitizer).

Here is how end of gtest report looks like in console (`stdout` and `stderr` on one screen)

```bash
[==========] 1604 tests from 146 test suites ran. (29473 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1604 tests.

  YOU HAVE 31 DISABLED TESTS


=================================================================
==820==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 912 byte(s) in 8 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x75d98d in malloc (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x75d98d)
    #1 0x86b6ec7 in CRYPTO_zalloc (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x86b6ec7)

Indirect leak of 6848 byte(s) in 130 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x75d98d in malloc (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x75d98d)
    #1 0x86b6ec7 in CRYPTO_zalloc (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x86b6ec7)

Indirect leak of 1354 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x75d98d in malloc (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x75d98d)
    #1 0x8671a91 in asn1_enc_save (/home/User/repo/SomeNiceProduct/Src/Debug/UnitTests+0x8671a91)
    
...
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 11547 byte(s) leaked in 193 allocation(s).
```

Application exits normally (no crash) with exit code `1`.

Now I wonder how I can make this: address and undefined behavior sanitizer reports, to be nicely visible in Jenkins without looking directly into a logs?

I already used `xuint` to visualize unit test results.

What would be perfect solution?
I'd like to register some observers to gtest which will be able to cooperate with sanitizers. So when test completes my gtest observer should ask sanitizer to:

- print report now (not at the end of application, but at the end of each test)
- give current status, so specific I can see which test caused leak and fail specific test
- reset address sanitizer to zero status, so next test could be run with clean slate.

Registering gtest observers is not a problem. Interacting with sanitizers is.

If there is some alternative solution which let me know quickly what and where it is wrong it would be great.

Note I do not want to rebuild dependencies to get better reports.

If there is some Jenkins parser/tool for sanitizers it would be great solution too.